Laravel Livewire rules with unique attribute
In my AddUser Livewire component, I have the following rule:
#[Rule('required|max:50|unique:users,name')]
public $name;

Which of course does its job. But when I'm trying to update a user in the database I have the following rule:
#[Rule('required|max:50|unique:users,name,' . $this->user?->id)]

I am getting an error with this:
Constant expression contains invalid operations
I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong, since this is what I would do normally in Laravel, and I cannot find anything online about this. Any explanation and/or solution to make it work without having to use public function rules()?

I did some research and found that when using the #[Rule()] format is not capable of performing the ignore unique rule. So you have to use the Rule object.
Livewire docs for Rule object.
Here is a good GitHub discussion related to your problem.

Too bad! Thanks for the help!
